# git commit to remote repository not working

Tags: git, commit

Not understanding why my commit to remote git repo is not working.

So I clone a branch from the remote repo

```
git clone -b MYBRANCH git@172.27.1.111:/home/my.git
```

I modify a file called test

```
git diff shows the change

diff --git a/test b/test
index e69de29..9ccc327 100644
--- a/test
+++ b/test
@@ -0,0 +1,3 @@
+changed.
+
+
```

when I go to commit, no changes are added to the commit.

```
git commit -m "changed the test file"
# On branch MCKINLEY
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   modified:   test
#
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to add it to the index.

```
git add test
```

Guessing you might be new to git.. check out [here](http://book.git-scm.com/1_the_git_index.html) for a good intro to what the index is.

Comment: test was added and I got that as part of the clone, it is not a new file, thus the modified:   test. Am I not reading that correctly?

Comment: @reza in git, `git add` means something different than, say, `svn add`. I'd encourage you to find and complete a quick tutorial on git, to make your life and others' easier.

Comment: If you come from svn, you'll also find branching quite different.  Basically you do it a LOT less because the D (Distributed) in DVCS makes it so tht you need to branch a lot less, and also you branch for different reasons (basically larger more separate changes, like a version upgrade).

Comment: 'commit -a' does do the trick but it effectively 'skips' the index.  If you're going to be using git often I recommend learning how to leverage the index.  You might end up doing 'commit -a' a large percent of the time but the other times the index can really get you out of a bind.

Answer (score 2):

Isn't the message telling you what to do?

Do `git add test`

Note that `git add` is not only to add a new file, but also to add / stage modifications to an existing file

Answer (score 1):

I recommend trying a git status to see if the file needs to be added.

```
git status
```

If you still need to add files to the commit then either do git add . or git add

```
git add .
```

Then your commit should be ready to go

```
git commit -a
```

Hope that helps!